# Gastby - ReactDOM: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm trying to Use Conditional Rendering using the example from [Reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) **in a Gastby project** to render a reusable component based on a condition

*my end goal here would be to render my component differently whether i'm in landscape or portrait but i'd like to understand why it's not working even for basic conditions*

I'm stuck at the very first step of the React example with the error ReactDOM: Target container is not a DOM element, here is the code for the component i'm trying to create

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function PortaitMode(props) {
  return <h1>It's in LandscapeMode</h1>;
}

function LandscapeMode(props) {
  return <h1>It's in PortraitMode</h1>;
}

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const isInPortait = props.isInPortait;
  if (isInPortait) {
    return <PortaitMode />;
  }
  return <LandscapeMode />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  // Try changing to isLoggedIn={true}:
  <MyComponent isInPortait={false} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I've tried to put `<div id="root"></div>` in my index.html or even change `document.getElementById("root")` with `document.getElementById("___gatsby")` *but it worked oddly showing the h1 tag on my page by just importing myComponent into the other .js file without even using it ...*

If someone could help it would be great ! : )

Comment: Hi, what I normally do to check if it's a react issue or an external issue is testing my logic in a sandbox like `codesandbox` here I've pasted your code and it seems to work https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-resonance-7hzob?file=/src/index.js therefor I think it's something Gatbsy specific

Comment: Yes : ) it's basically them same code as https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html example but i'm trying to figure out why it's not working inside a Gatsby project :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
import React from "react";

function PortaitMode(props) {
  return <h1>It's in LandscapeMode</h1>;
}

function LandscapeMode(props) {
  return <h1>It's in PortraitMode</h1>;
}

export default function MyComponent(props) { 
  const isInPortait = props.isInPortait;

  if (isInPortait) {
    return <PortaitMode />;
  }
  return <LandscapeMode />;
}
```

Then, in another page/component, you can:

```
import MyComponent from 'your/component/path'

const IndexPage = () =>{

return <main><MyComponent isInPortait={false} /></main>

}

export default IndexPage
```

If your `IndexPage` is inside `/pages/index.js` you will see your component depending on the `isInPortait` `prop`.

---

P.S: you can save the following line:

```
const isInPortait = props.isInPortait;
```

By adding a destructuring `props` in the component declaration like:

```
function portaitMode() {
  return <h1>It's in LandscapeMode</h1>;
}

function landscapeMode() {
  return <h1>It's in PortraitMode</h1>;
}

export default function MyComponent({isInPortait}) {     
  if (isInPortait) {
    return portaitMode();
  }
  return landscapeMode();
}
```

Note: in addition, the components are not doing anything with the `props` so you can avoid passing it.

You can even make it shorter, but it's completely up to you:

```
export default function MyComponent({isInPortait}) {  
    return isInPortait ? portaitMode() : landscapeMode();
}
```